# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT kubernetes minikube service

Tags: kubernetes, identityserver4, minikube

I am getting ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when trying to access minikube service in localhost.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: identityserver
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: identityserver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: identityserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: identityserver
        image: identityserver:0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5001 
        imagePullPolicy: "Never"
```

I have created service as following.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: identityserver
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: identityserver
  ports:
  - port: 5001
    nodePort: 30002
```

I am trying to load in my local browser using following command. But it is not getting accessible in localhost. Internal kubernetes apps are able to communicate with service but not externally.

```
minikube service identityserver
```

I tried making type as clusterip and then it worked with port forwarding and only nodeport is having issue accessing.

```
kubectl port-forward service/identityserver 18080:5001 --address 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Try `targetPort: 5001` https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ `spec.ports` section

Comment: @Gupta not working. not sure why but even simplest service created from following is not working somehow.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

Comment: Hi Anonymous Creator! How do you run minikube (on Linux, Mac, windows+wsl2, windows+docker desktop)?

Comment: Today I formatted my machine and installed everything fresh. But by no luck even simplest example is working.
windows+docker (docker asked me to install wsl2 though)

Comment: So, it is still NOT working?

Comment: no. I reported issue to github as I am helpless now. Will wait till their reply or may be I am tryinh ubuntu to check now and will use ubuntu (if it works) till this works in windows.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the Docker driver. I was able to run this with VirtualBox driver.

So I just had to start using VirtualBox driver (Even though virtualization was enabled in my machine it was giving an error. so had to append the `--no-vtx-check` flag, you can skip that if not facing an error without that flag)

`minikube start --driver=virtualbox --no-vtx-check`

Comment: I am able to access both ingress url using windows browser and Nodeport service (from your simplest example link) by using Docker Desktop (enabled k8s) on Windows.

Comment: Using minikube and windows 11?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of trying `minikube` on Windows + docker:

- Docker Desktop app (with `Enable Kubernetes` option)
- Docker Desktop app (`without` enabling Kubernetes option) and installing `minikube to wsl2`
- No Docker Desktop at all, installing docker and minikube in wsl2

Let's test it with the link you gave in comments - [Set up Ingress on Minikube with the NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/).

##### Docker Desktop v.20.10.12 (with `Enable Kubernetes` option v.1.22.5), Win10, wsl2 backend.

1. **Enable Kubernetes** in Docker Desktop.
2. Check if `ingress-controller` is installed:

```sh
$ kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
```

The output should be similar to:

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS    AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-g9g49        0/1     Completed   0          11m
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-rqp78         0/1     Completed   1          11m
ingress-nginx-controller-59b45fb494-26npt   1/1     Running     0          11m
```

3. Create a Deployment using the following command:

```
kubectl create deployment web --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
```

4. Expose the Deployment:

```
kubectl expose deployment web --type=NodePort --port=8080
```

5. Create `example-ingress.yaml` from the following file:

```yaml
$ kubectl apply -f example-ingress.yaml
$ cat example-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1    
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx   # this line is essential!
  rules:
    - host: hello-world.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

6. Verify the IP address is set:

```
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS              ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   <none>   hello-world.info   localhost    80      38s
```

7. Add the following line to the bottom of the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file on your computer (you will need administrator access):

```
127.0.0.1 hello-world.info
```

8. **DONE**.  Open hello-world.info in a browser.
9. How to access the NodePort service? In `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` find these lines:

```
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.1.179 host.docker.internal
192.168.1.179 gateway.docker.internal
```

Use this IP and node port: `curl 192.168.1.179:portNumber`

Comment: for me, ingress address is showing empty somehow even though waited for so long.

Comment: It is, if you use ingress downloaded from k8s website. Add `ingressClassName: nginx` line like in my example.